# Install 14.04 Error mounting /dev/sr0

Tags: 14.04

Error mounting `/dev/sr0` at `/media/james/Ubuntu 14.04 LTS i386`: Command-line

```
mount -t "iso9660" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500" "/dev/sr0" "/media/james/Ubuntu 14.04 LTS i386"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   `dmesg | tail  or so`
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This looks related to the install disk, you can try again or try making a new disk. Can you confirm the drive/disk works, maybe in Windows?

Comment: i will try thru windows.i have a dual boot system running windows 7 aswell

Comment: Filesystem type "iso9660" refers to CD-R and DVD-R physical media formats. (?) `/dev/sr0` is usually the device pointer for floppy drives. I do not believe a floppy disk, or image file emulating a floppy disk, can have format "iso9660". The system is looking for structure and formatting the raw floppy image does not have. Perhaps try `-t "msdos"` or `-t "fat"` or `-t "vfat"`.